# Filtering an array of nested objects by string value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter an array with nested objects like this:

```
const items = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "subitems": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "test2",
                "subsubitems": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "test3",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "test4",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "test10",
        "subitems": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "test20",
                "subsubitems": [
                    {
                        "id": 30,
                        "name": "test30",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

const filteredResults = items.filter((item) =>
    item.subitems.some((subitem) =>
        subitem.subsubitems.some((subsubitem) =>
            subsubitem.name.includes('test3')
        )
    )
)

console.log(filteredResults)
```

But it's not filtering correctly, the original array is being returned. Right now I'm just attempting to filter at the subsubitems level. Ultimately I want to return an array with any matches to name at any level.

So `test2` would return an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "subitems": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "test2",
                "subsubitems": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "test3",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "test4",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And `test3` would return an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "subitems": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "test2",
                "subsubitems": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "test3",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "test10",
        "subitems": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "test20",
                "subsubitems": [
                    {
                        "id": 30,
                        "name": "test30",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And `test` would return everything.

Comment: Your current implementation is returning the whole array because `test30` includes `test3`.

Comment: Yes but if I search for `test3` I want it to return `test3` and `test30` but not `test4`.

Comment: So you want to filter at each level? Not check for the value at any level to determine if the top level item should be included?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If level 2 matches then everything from level 3 that falls under level 2 should be included.

Comment: why not take the same key for children objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the process is:

1. If the current level's `name` includes the search value, include the current level and all children in the `subitems` or `subsubitems` arrays as available.
2. Otherwise, repeat the same check for each item in the `subitems` or `subsubitems` arrays as available and, if there are any results, include the current item.

I think the following sample gets you this behavior. Notice that when searching for "test2", the items with names "test3" and "test4" are included like in your question. Also, "test20" is included because this is searching at the `subitems` level in addition to the `subsubitems` level and "test20" includes "test2".

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", subitems: [
    { id: 2, name: "test2", subsubitems:[
      { id: 3, name: "test3" },
      { id: 4, name: "test4" }
    ]}
  ]},
  { id: 10, name: "test10", subitems: [
    { id: 20, name: "test20", subsubitems: [
      { id: 30, name: "test30"}
    ]}
  ]}
];

const deepFilter = (items, value) => items.reduce((arr, cur) => {
  if (cur.name.includes(value)) arr.push(cur);
  else if (cur.hasOwnProperty('subitems')) {
    const subItems = deepFilter(cur.subitems, value);
    if (subItems.length) {
      cur.subitems = subItems;
      arr.push(cur);
    }
  }
  else if (cur.hasOwnProperty('subsubitems')) {
    const subSubItems = deepFilter(cur.subsubitems, value);
    if (subSubItems.length) {
      cur.subsubitems = subSubItems;
      arr.push(cur);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log('test2:');
console.log(deepFilter(items, 'test2'));

console.log('test3:');
console.log(deepFilter(items, 'test3'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a function for checking the actual level and search for sub levels and if a sublevel has a lenght take the actual level as result.

```js
const
    filter = childrenKey => o => {
        if (o.name === value) return o;
        const childrenValues = (o[childrenKey] || []).flatMap(filter('sub' + childrenKey));
        return childrenValues.length ? { ...o, [childrenKey]: childrenValues } : [];
    },
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "test1", subitems: [{ id: 2, name: "test2", subsubitems: [{ id: 3, name: "test3" }, { id: 4, name: "test4" }] }] }, { id: 10, name: "test10", subitems: [{ id: 20, name: "test20", subsubitems: [{ id: 30, name: "test30" }] }] }],
    value = 'test3',
    result = data.flatMap(filter('subitems'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```